# 'func': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

function identifier not found. Please who can fix this error?

[defined function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDG2.jpg)

[function recall in int main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg5iI.jpg)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with text, not with pictures or links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to move the entire function (for organization purposes), you could also declare a [prototype](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/) before main() like this:

```
void func();
```

A prototype only defines what comes in (the arguments, in this case none) and what goes out (void), you basically promise the compiler that the function body (what the function actually does) will be defined later in the code.

Comment: its worked.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If the images you posted are from the same file:

Main is defined around line 100, func() is defined on line 163. This means that when the compiler compiles main, it doesn't yet know about func. Try moving func() such that it is defined before main().

Comment: its worked.. thanks a lot